# databinding include parameter can not auto upcast

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a include layout
[include layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyh0K.jpg)

[include layout param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxQHF.jpg)
the include layout viewModel param type is BaseSeekBarRecycleViewVM

[set a PictureFrameMenuVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDhys.jpg)
I set a PictureFrameMenuVM Which extend BaseSeekBarRecycleViewVM

but get an error :

> Error:(123, 35) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'bind:viewModel'
>   with parameter type
>   com.example.whensunset.pictureprocessinggraduationdesign.viewModel.includeLayoutVM.PictureFrameMenuVM
>   on
>   com.example.whensunset.pictureprocessinggraduationdesign.databinding.ActivityPictureProcessingPictureTextMenuBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `bind:viewModel` tag and bind the viewModel directly from code.

Like so:

```
binding.pictureFrameMenu.setViewModel(new YourViewModelName());
```

where binding is the instance of your DataBindingLayout.

Comment: you are right ,  but I want konw The reason I am incorrect . And Can I try to write in xml instead of writing in code . thanks

Comment: Because the tag doesn't exist by default. To use it, you'd have to create a BindingAdapter, I think.

P.S.: I have never used BindingAdapter before.